Have a user access some values of a variable and not all of them in Grafana?
I have a dashboard in Grafana. I added a variable and it has a lot of values. I want to know if I can hide some of these values from some users. Meaning that some users can only see half of the values of this variable in my dashboard. Is something like that can be done?
I tried to see into the documentation but I really didn't get any help.

If your variable is based on a query, you can filter the query's result by using the global __user variable .
For example:
SELECT id,name 
FROM sometable 
WHERE owner = ${__user.email}

I am not familiar with a way of doing this for other variable types.
